# Visual C++ 6.0 Link Error

Tags: c++

Does anybody know about this linker error in Visual C++?

> PGPkeys.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_PGPclCloseClientPrefs

Comment: Erm... you *do* realize that VC++6 is 12 years old, is full of bugs and does not conform to the C++ standard?

Comment: Yes but there are legacy applications out there that need to be maintained and the cost of migrating the entire application to a newer version - just fixing all the errors could take weeks depending on the applcation size - was probably not deemed worth it. I've been in that situation michael and feel your pain.

Answer (score 2):

Unresolved externals are usually due to missing binary (a DLL or a static lib). Check directory paths to libraries your code needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out in what library/DLL the symbol PGPclCloseClientPrefs is defined.

If mbadawi23's answer doesn't solve your problem, think about the following:

I think *imp* might indicate an environment mismatch, so make sure you're using the linker that came with VC++ 6.  I do not remember VC++6 mangling imported/exported symbol names in that way, but, I could be wrong.

If worst comes to worst, look up making a def file for the DLL in which PGPclCloseClientPrefs lives and export the symbol that way.